# Which model of Slow Cooker is kosher for Shabbat use?

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, cooking-bishul, appliances

There are multiple types of slow cookers and crock pots and I'd like a recommendation of a specific one that can be used for Shabbat. I remember reading about the popular type of slow cooker with removable pots being a halachic problem because the pots usually don't touch the bottom of the heating component, which renders the heating method as insulation.

Can I get a recommendation for something that won't cause any halachic problems?

Comment: "Any halachic problems"... like cooking on shabbat?  Any slow-cooker when used improperly is melachah so they all cause some halakhic problems

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the popular type of slow cooker with the removable pot is a problem right out of the gate. I'm just asking for a model that can be used properly. Would an electric skillet perhaps be appropriate for slow cooking or keeping food on on shabbat?